# How to pass ViewBag value to java script function in razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need pass **ViewBag** value to *java script function* in razor. ViewBag filled by string and I use this code but get error that :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: IsAirTour is not defined

IsAirTour is value of ViewBag

```
var RunFilter = function (cls) {
            var $grid = $('#grid');
            $grid.isotope({ filter: '.' + cls + '' })
            SetHeightEls('#grid .All');
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            RunFilter(@((string)ViewBag.Cls) ); //Error
        });
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 RunFilter('@ViewBag.Cls'); //Error
```

Instead

```
RunFilter(@((string)ViewBag.Cls) ); //Error
```

Comment: Better, but you need to explain what you have done too.